# iframe or an alternative?

Tags: iframe

i'm looking for a solution to be able to display content from an external URL which should dynamically match visitor's browser as height and width, between a header and footer div. a very basic illustration can be found [here](http://imgur.com/pxBiWAo) . i'm looking to achieve this with maximum compability. anyone has any ideas/experiences with this? i'd appreciate any opinions from now on.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't ask for opinions. Ask for answers. Anyways, why no iframe?

Comment: well, i've tried it but having some problems while placing it between divs and i'm getting different views on different browsers. this of course is something to do with myself since i'm not experienced enough but on the other hand i also was wondering whether there's a better solution for this or not.

Comment: concerning compability, i guess the best solution, if not only real solution is an iframe.

Comment: what's that in your mind?

Comment: Reading the foreign page you want to display on yours serverside (perl, php, .net, ...) and requesting it via Ajax preventing cross-domain errors. That's like a sledgehammer to crack a nut, and it's probably not going to work flawlessly, so the iframe still is the best solution. It's nothing else than a second browser window in your page. Keep it simple.

Comment: thanks Fabian, ya that even sounds more than that... :) from what I learned after my research, all parent divs of iframe should have 100% width/height to be able to make that iframe 100%, however, that's not possible in my case. is there a work around for that? the frame is not stretching the page while it's between header/footer divs.

Comment: always glad to help :)  btw: try `float: left; height: 100%;` on the iframe.

Comment: thanks again Fabian, that almost did the trick. just got one minor point left and working on it. thank you Fabian, have a great one.